# Ubuntu cannot dump the server's database in WinSCP

Tags: server, ssh

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, WinSCP version 5.15.5.

I am trying to dump my local database using this command:
`ssh root@178.62.203.226 "mysqldump -u root -p mcc | gzip -9" > dblocal.sql.gz`.

I receive this error: `Permission denied (publickey)`. I am using a ssh key to login into the server. Do I have to use another command to avoid the ssh issue?

This is the `sshd_conf` file:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try if ssh root suceeds to open a shell ? `ssh root@178.62.203.226`

Comment: It throws the same error

Comment: I am using WinSCP console window and `178.62.203.226` is the ip address of my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already logged into your server with WinSCP, do not try to login again (using `ssh`) from its [Console window](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_console). Use `mysqldump` directly:

```
mysqldump -u root -pmcc | gzip -9 > dblocal.sql.gz
```

Comment: It worked but without the space after -p: `-pmcc`. After that I saw it is only 203 kb. Do you think this is ok because I think the database is much bigger?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot answer that. That's too vague question. We do not know anything about your database. And it's a different question anyway. -- Though didn't consider that the dump file is compressed?